# What is the proper site to ask for some links?

Tags: discussion, computer-science-se

I've got a particular question to ask for some **http-links** where I can find problem sets **with test cases** dealing with specific area of computer science.

It's not the thing to discuss, hence I can't post it to stackoverflow. Though I am pre-assured that I'd get some help there.

Which site of stackexchange network can I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are **NO** Stack Exchange network sites that I know of that you can solicit for list of answers.

Either **one** answer is ***all*** right, or you have no answer.

Comment: Ha, thanks for the fix @Oded ^_^

Comment: Okay, that's clear. But you understand that I am more interested in the result than in the acceptance stuff etc.
Do you think they close it for violation if I ask such kind of question?

Comment: @Alec yes, they most probably would.